# User object in session empty post google sign-in

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

So i'm using the google provider. Inside the callback signIn function, when the user authenticate i make an api request to my backend to check if he's already an existing user with email adresse. if yes, i want to redirect him to homepage if not i want to redirect him to a form page with a series of question. I managed to that with the following

```
async signIn ({ user, account, profile }) {
            if (account.provider === 'google') {
                return await authApi
                    .signInWithGoogle({ account, profile })
                    .then(function (response) {
                    // i send 200 http status code that means it's a new user
                            return '/application-form'
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        if (error.response.status === 409) {
                            return '/'
                        }
                    });
                
            } 
}
```

Everything works fine, but the there's a catch : THE USER OBJECT RETURNED BY SESSION CALLBACK IS EMPTY !
To solve this i tried the following :

```
async signIn ({ user, account, profile }) {
            if (account.provider === 'google') {
                return await authApi
                    .signInWithGoogle({ account, profile })
                    .then(function (response) {
                                              // i send 200 http status code that means it's a new user
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        if (error.response.status === 409) {
                            return true
                        }
                    });
                
            } 
}
```

Post login user gets redirected the same login page but the SESSION OBJECT GETS CREATED. Please Tell me why when i return a url path i get an empty object ! I M TRYING FOR HOURS TO SOLVE THIS BUT NO ISSUE

Nextjs auth api file

```
session: {
  strategy: 'jwt',
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
},
callbacks: {
  async signIn ({ user, account, profile }) {
    if (account.provider === 'google') {
        return await authApi
        .signInWithGoogle({ account, profile })
        .then(function (response) {
            return '/'
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response.status === 409) {
                return '/'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't the user object returned in the `response` variable? You're not returning the object, but just a string based on status. Console log `response` to see what's there, and you could do something like `return { path: '/', user: response.user }` Keep in mind that's pseudocode and I don't remember the shape of the user object returned, but that should get you mostly there.

Comment: But why when i do return true the user object gets created with the google profile account?

Comment: @JoelHager tried your answer, still not working. i did put the currect user object with email, name and image

Comment: My suggestion wasn't suggested as a 'fix' because I don't know how/where you're storing the user object. The first step is logging `response` in the then statement. What is coming back in response?

Comment: @JoelHager i'm getting the response i send from my rest api with express. Which is in case of not an existing user , a 200 status with the user object . if he does exist i send 409 status with the existing user object so far the backend is working fine

Comment: Right - but the call to signInWithGoogle should have the user object attached to it. Right above your `return '/'` just put `console.log(response)` and see what's there.

Comment: Right now you're just sending statuses and paths based on the result of the call - not the returned data as well.

Comment: @JoelHager i indeed , retuned response.data . And i have the user object with email, image, and full name properties. the problem is if i return that i can't redirect the user

Comment: Why not return the user object and status and reroute client side? You can protect routes client side

Comment: How do i reroute client side when i'm handline all the logic in the [...nextauth file].js . and the signIn callback  return a promise that i can use client side. Also whatever user object i return, the session object gets create with the account object returned from google....

Comment: I'm really confused.... why didn't next provide a way to redirect users to different pages based on an express api response....